# Add Azure Application to another Azure Application Role

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Simple case: I have two Azure Applications

[image]

TaskTrackerWebApp application has multiple Roles defined. I would like to add AG360DataApiClient application to one of the roles.

[image]

But no matter if i use Name or Application ID of the AG360DataApiClient i still cant find it.

In TaskTrackerWebApp i also defined a role with "Application" allowedmemberTypes

[image]

So, how would i add an application to another application role? Powershell voodoo?

Thank you.

Update: There was somethign wrong with my Application registration. I deleted and recreated it and now i can assign an application to a Role.

[image]

Comment: Hm, have you tried using the application id?

Comment: @MartinBrandl But no matter if i use Name or Application ID of the AG360DataApiClient i still cant find it. So, how would i add an application to another application role?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, your problem is that you are trying to add an application to a role on a blade that says Users and groups :)

Roles are given to apps as *app permissions*. Internally they are called appRoleAssignments actually, literally assigning a role to a service principal.

So go to the AG360DataApiClient app registration, go to Required permissions, and add & grant the App permissions. If you can't find the permissions there, make sure the roles have Application as an allowed member type.